# How do I make my microservices only accessible by the api gateway

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am learning Microservices using Spring Cloud, and I learned that one of the advantages API Gateway is centralized Authentication, but what is the point of having centralized Authentication if I still need to have authentication to my microservices? How can I hide this services and can only be accessible via the API Gateway and/or the Discovery Server. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336483/how-do-make-my-microservices-only-accessible-by-the-api-gateway

Comment: While the API Gateway handles authentication and authorization for incoming requests, it also forwards requests to the appropriate microservice. To ensure that your microservices are only accessible via the API Gateway you can configure your network infrastructure to prevent direct access to the microservices from outside the network.